# MySQL split into two tables or keep everything in one

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I've currently got a generic `Users` table with the following columns

```
user_id
first_name
last_name
join_date
last_active
email
password
rank
status
```

Some users (the ones with rank = 3) will provide some extra information like telephone number, secondary email, birthday, etc (total 15 fields). I was wondering if I should add these columns on this table or if I should create another table and connect with the `Users` one with user_id. Something like this:

```
user_id
all new columns
```

Which one would be the best option?

Comment: It depends how many records you have. If it is a reasonable amount, keeping everything in one table is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Gab I would say no more than 1000 within the next couple of years.

Comment: one table is fine

Comment: This is an interesting question, you can take a look at what is called Single Table Inheritance. I do not know enough to pretend i can argue about if and when you should use it, but you should definitely google it

Answer (score 0):

The two table approach is viable.

To get all columns from both tables:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
    FROM t1
    LEFT JOIN t2  USING(user_id);
```

I as assuming that the row in t2 will be sometimes missing, yet you want to get the row, with `NULLs` for the missing data -- hence `LEFT JOIN`.

Of course, if you know that you won't need t2, don't do the `JOIN`.  But there is no harm, other than a little performance, in always doing the `JOIN`.

Is it the "best option"?  That is hard to say without knowing more about your system.  But, based on what information you mention, it seems like a 'good' option.